# How do I attach a text component to a 2D sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game has this system where the player is rewarded with hearts.

Whenever a heart appears, it's supposed to appear with a value on it (say, +5). I did some googling and everything said I need to attach a canvas to the sprite and then a text component to the canvas. However, this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Do you have any idea about TextMeshPro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the following structure

[image]

Sample Image settings: (Here you'll want to replace the "Source Image" with your heart sprite)

[image]

Sample Text settings: (Although I recommend using the TextMeshPro component instead)

[image]

Result:

[image]